# Where the background image get loaded? (Need to change it)

Tags: ios

I need to change a initial background of an application.

when I debug an IOS code, I found the initial windows's background get set even before I enter
the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I am wondering what's the possible place to set the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project's summary settings, you can set the default loading image. Here you can also set the Icon!

Project > summary

Make sure that the images you choose have the correct dimensions

..

If you would like to do this manually, swap the project's files called "Default.png" and Default-568h.png" to the ones of your choice. Those files are located in the projects root folder

See: 
https://www.google.se/search?q=project+summary+xcode&safe=off&client=safari&hl=en-gb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=dp8FUrnhOpDP4QSkiIH4Ag&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAA&biw=320&bih=460#biv=i%7C4%3Bd%7CX9orTmZ6VqxFQM%3A

Comment: Weird, it is not here.

Comment: Mark your target, not your project

Comment: Yes, I mark the target, but cannot find background image there.

Comment: It should be, see my edit link

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a matter of "changing" the image, rather uploading a new one. You add the image to your resources folder, and then you can change the background image in the Inspector in the graphical side of the interface. Click on the UIImageView you want to change, and then go to the Inspector. There should be an "Image" option, where you can type your uploaded image name.